# In wix is it possible to set the application pool for a website?

Tags: wix, wix-iisextension

I want to set the application pool for a website that I'm installing, but there is **no virtual directory or web application**. The website is contained directly in the `website` entry in IIS and I want wix to set the application pool for that website.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked that the [WebAppPool Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/webapppool.html)?

This article '[creating a web application installer ...](http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2011/02/25/creating-a-web-application-installer-with-wix-3.5-and-visual-yet-again.aspx)' may provide you with some useful info e.g.

```
<!-- Define App Pool - identity if not set defaults to: ApplicationPoolIdentity -->
<iis:WebAppPool Id="AppPool" Name="[VD][WEBSITE_ID]" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" 
                IdleTimeout="0" RecycleMinutes="0" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated">
</iis:WebAppPool>

<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VDir" Alias="[VD]" 
                   Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                   WebSite="SelectedWebSite">
  <iis:MimeMap Id="SilverlightMimeType" Extension=".xap" 
               Type="application/x-silverlight-app" />
  <iis:WebApplication Id="MyWebAppApplication" WebAppPool="AppPool" 
                      Name="[VD][WEBSITE_ID]" />
  <iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebSite_Properties" AnonymousAccess="yes" 
                        WindowsAuthentication="no" DefaultDocuments="Default.aspx" />
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

to connect them the `iis:WebApplication/@WebAppPool` entry is used to reference the AppPool `iis:WebAppPool/@Id`

One other suggestion is to update the WebApplication of the WebSite like this e.g.

```
<Component Id="WebSite" Guid="PUT-YOUR-GUID-HERE">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <iis:WebSite Id="WebSite" Directory="WebSiteRoot" Description="[WEBSITEDESCRIPTION]" >
        <iis:WebApplication Id="WebSiteApplication" Name="[WEBSITEDESCRIPTION]" WebAppPool="MyAppPool" />
    </iis:WebSite>
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="MyAppPool" Name="[APPPOOLNAME]" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: I also found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028848/setting-the-apppool-of-a-website-element-in-wix-3-6 which may help

Comment: I've seen that question actually, and it comes to the conclusion that wix has an odd limitation: it can't set the app pool for the website, but it can do it for a virtual directory. I asked again because I thought maybe it has been fixed in a newer version. Having said that, that is why your answer doesn't actually answer my question :)

Comment: Perhaps but you haven't described what you've tried so far so I didn't know you knew about that Wix Element

Comment: What about the updated approach regarding the WebApplication within the WebSite?

Comment: Well after further testing, my conclusion from yesterday was invalid. It does work with your edit (that's actually what I was trying but in my case I didn't uninstall the website entry, meaning the first website installed with the wrong app pool was staying there the whole time through all my installs/uninstalls...)

Answer (score 4):

@user145400 said:

> I've seen that question actually, and it comes to the conclusion that
>   wix has an odd limitation: it can't set the app pool for the website,
>   but it can do it for a virtual directory. I asked again because I
>   thought maybe it has been fixed in a newer version. Having said that,
>   that is why your answer doesn't actually answer my question

Yes you can set pool for WebSite element, do it like that:

```
<iis:WebAppPool Id="MyWebSite_AppPool"
                Name="[POOLNAME]"
                Identity="networkService"
                ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
                ManagedPipelineMode="integrated"/>
            <!--define web site-->
<iis:WebSite Id="MyWebSite_Website"
             Description="[WEBSITENAME]"
             AutoStart="yes"
             StartOnInstall="yes"
             ConfigureIfExists="yes"
             Directory="INSTALLDIR">

     <iis:WebApplication Id="MY_WebApp"
                         Name="MY Web Site"
                         WebAppPool="MyWebSite_AppPool"
                         ScriptTimeout="360" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

As you can see using `iis:WebApplication element` in *iis:WebSite element* with attribute **WebAppPool** its possible :)